# Azure function: make schedule cron a variable in function.json

Tags: azure, cron, azure-functions

I have an Azure function. For codes, I only have **init**.py and function.json.

function.json is like the following:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "timer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 1 */12 * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to make the "12" in schedule a variable (eg. called IntervalVariable) and get it from **init**.py?

So that it becomes

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "timer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 1 */{IntervalVariable} * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I believe you can bind the whole configuration setting instead of part of it using binding expression -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns. so `"schedule": "%IntervalVariable%"` should bind the schedule configuration setting with IntervalVariable enviornment variable (which is bind to app settings or environment variable)

Comment: Thanks @user1672994. %InternvalVariable% in Azure application setting can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized this can be done easily with %IntervalVariable% and add a key-value pair in Azure application settings.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "timer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 1 */%IntervalVariable% * * *"
    }
  ]
}
```

And then add

```
key: IntervalVariable
value: 12
```

in Azure function application settings.